# glm with missing values

Tags: r, glm

I'm creating a model with a binary response (purchase vs no purchase) and I have some variables that should predict the response, some have different levels, some are just numbers. So I'm making a multiple logistic regression. The code I'm using now is:

```
Data.omit = na.omit(Data)
model.null = glm(aankoop ~ 1, data=Data.omit,family =binomial(link="logit"))
model.full = glm(aankoop ~.,data=Data.omit,family = binomial(link="logit"))
step(model.null,scope = list(upper=model.full),direction="both",test="Chisq",data=Data)
model.final = glm(aankoop ~ duration + number_of_pages + recentvisits +householdtypology_gfk + device + os + engine + browser + medium,data=tabelx3,family = binomial(link="logit"),na.action(na.pass))
summary(model.final)
```

I have some questions about this. My data has a lot of missing values because of one variable. It would be a shame to remove all rows with a missing value because of that one variable, a lot of information would be lost.

If I look at the code, model.final doesn't use the dataset Data.omit, so does that mean that this includes all rows with missing values? I tried using na.action(na.pass), but I discovered if I use na.action(na.omit), the result is just the same, so what is the difference?

Is there a possibility to create a model based on all the rows with NA values? One detail is that the variable with the many missing values has NA, it means that a user is not registered. Only if it's not NA, it means the user has registered and has filled in this information. So the variable actually has a meaning if it's NA. If these values (for non-registered users) are predicted by values for registered users, I guess that's wrong.

Comment: Reading up on multiple imputation and the `mice` package might be a good place to start

Comment: And do you have an idea how na.action(na.pass) works? Why does na.action(na.pass) and na.action(na.omit) give the same result?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `na.action=na.pass` and `na.action=na.omit`? That should give you an error for `na.pass`

Comment: You could be right, I'm following the method as described on this site: http://rcompanion.org/rcompanion/e_07.html. I'm still unsure if the data I'm analysing are all the rows or only the rows without NA, because model.final does point to the original dataset and not Data.omit. Or does this take only rows without NA automatically?

Comment: I think you can find the answer in this question. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46692/how-the-na-values-are-treated-in-glm-in-r